# Migrate from Thunderbird to Mutt

Tags: thunderbird, mutt

I am contemplating moving from Thunderbird to Mutt (provided it is feasible) to move to a faster, simpler application.

My current Thunderbird set-up consists of multiple IMAP accounts (gmail and google apps). Only selected folders (read labels) in each IMAP account are stored locally. For all other folders, I glance through the headers and open a message only if I find it interesting. I also use folder bookmarks to navigate to folders quickly. I also move messages across folders with keyboard shortcuts.

Is it possible to replicate the set-up in Mutt? Can someone share/ point to a sample muttrc file that does the same thing? It would be great if the muttrc file is adequately commented.

On a side note, will it also be possible to import my messages from Thunderbird locally? That will save me considerable network traffic (about 2GB data stored locally).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do all the things you want to do with `Mutt`, and much more.

Multiple accounts are possible with `Mutt`. Personally I have only used multiple gmail imap accounts, as described in this [article here](http://dev.mutt.org/doc/manual.html#account-hook), but it is feasible to set them up and move between them. It is not necessary to repeat the information here, but it has a lot to do with how the 'account hooks' and 'folder hooks' are set up; the article explains it well.

However, you can achieve it without `folder-hooks`: see my answer here:

- [How to manage multiple imap accounts with mutt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122480/how-to-manage-multiple-imap-accounts-with-mutt)

To navigate between folders, you can use macros, as these well known ones demonstrate:

```
macro index,pager gi "<change-folder>=INBOX<enter>" "Go to inbox"
macro index,pager ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter>" "Go to all mail"
```

More on how to move between folders and how messages can be moved across folders is explained [here](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttGuide/Actions) in great detail.

Indeed, messages can be exported from `Thunderbird` in the `mbox` format and then read in `Mutt`, as the Mutt wiki notes [here](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Folder). It will be necessary to install the `Thunderbird` import/export addon and then export the folders from Thunderbird in `mbox` format and then specify the folder in the `.muttrc`, by refering to [these notes](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttGuide/Folders).

Referring to your question in the comments: When you load up your inbox or when you switch between folders `Mutt` by default only loads the headers from the server, which I think is what you want. It only downloads the actual message when you click return to view the message. Hence, why we cache headers and messages for performance, and usually most people have standard entries like this in the `.muttrc`:

```
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
```

For offline availability, you may need to pair `Mutt` with another program called `offlineimap`, which is available in the repositories; a discussion is available [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-mutt-wiht-gmail-offline-no-lan-internet-948086/).

I've put these hints together (from the wiki and my own personal rc) into a rough [`muttrc`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1482665/) but you may have to test and modify it for your own purposes, and obviously add your own details, but it should be a useful starting point.

Comment: This is useful, indeed. But could you please point me to the part 'Only selected folders (read labels) in each IMAP account are stored locally. For all other folders, I glance through the headers and open a message only if I find it interesting.' Also, will these messages be available even when I am off-line?

Comment: @deshmukh Please see my edit.

Comment: @deshmukh I've added a sample muttrc, which you can base your own on.

Comment: thanks! The sample muttrc and other resources you have pointed to should be good enough for me to start-off. Expect to hear from me if I hit any roadblocks.

Comment: you might also want to use the mutt-patched package, which has a folder list sidebar and some other useful features added.

Comment: @deshmukh See my edit- new .muttrc pasted here in this question and also see my answer for [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122480/how-to-manage-multiple-imap-accounts-with-mutt)- a good way of using multiple accounts.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know how helpful can this be, but I've found something called Muttrc Builder, an online app to create `.muttrc`: http://www.muttrcbuilder.org/. And [Mutt Documentation](http://www.mutt.org/#doc) has many examples to config files.

For importing question, next is from Mutt wiki:

### How to import messages from pine, thunderbird, kmail, evilution, ...?

> **mutt** understands some standard [FolderFormats](http://wiki.mutt.org/?FolderFormat). Find out what format the
>   other MUA uses, and when it's compatible, just copy them over to a
>   place for mutt to find them (and configure it per [MuttGuide/Folders](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttGuide/Folders)).
>   If it's a proprietary format, either use the [MUAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent) own export function,
>   or search the web for external tools which can convert to a
>   mutt-usable format, and proceed as before with configuring mutt to
>   find them.